# ES 6 Harmony async class method chaining

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-class

This is a simple JavaScript example:

```
class Test {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 0;
        this.b = 1;
    }

    doSomething = async () => {
        await this.doSomethingChained(1)
            .doSomethingChained(2)
            .doSomethingChained(3);
    };

    doSomethingChained = async (x) => {
        this.a = this.a + x;
        console.log('a is', this.a);
        return this;
    };
}
```

It is then started using a test method but this does not matter

```
test('Vorgang erfassen', async t => {

    const t1 = new Test();
    await t1.doSomething();
```

The console contains this:

```
a is 1
TypeError: _this2.doSomethingChained(...).doSomethingChained is not a function
```

I don't understand why `this.a` works, but `return this` not.
I can of course start the method one after the other, but I would love to use chaining.

```
doSomething = async () => {
    await this.doSomethingChained(1);
    await this.doSomethingChained(2);
    await this.doSomethingChained(3);
};
```

Works like a charm.

```
a is 1
a is 3
a is 6
```

Comment: async will return a promise right? so the this will be inside the .then(doSomethingChained(2))?

Comment: The "chaining" you desire is a syntax that implies synchronous execution. This is not compatible with the asynchronous nature of promises. You need `await` or `then`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chaining according to this syntax:

```
this.doSomethingChained(1).doSomethingChained(2)
```

... is by definition synchronous: JavaScript will evaluate the arguments and the function calls synchronously; there is nothing you can do about that. So this syntax is just not suitable for asynchronous code.

Asynchronous code by nature relies on callbacks. Even promises involve the asynchronous execution of callbacks. With `await` this is less visible, but nevertheless, the corresponding `async` function's execution context gets restored asynchronously, proceeding the execution after an `await` is resolved.

To your question:

> I don't understand why `this.a` works, but `return` this not.

`return this` *does* work, but by specification the value provided with the `return` statement in an `async` function defines the *promised* value, not the *return* value of `doSomethingChained`, since an `async` function *always* returns a promise (synchronously).

So in your code, the (synchronous!) return value of `doSomethingChained` is a promise, not `this`. This explains why you get the error.

Note that an `async` function is not very useful when it does not have an `await`. Without it you might as well use a normal function.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain your promises like below:

```
doSomething = async () => {
    await this.doSomethingChained(1)
       .then(() => this.doSomethingChained(2))
       .then(() => this.doSomethingChained(3));
};
```

Comment: Looks like more code than I want to write, I thought you could just chain promises by now.

Comment: @Nabor use your await other-wise it will create promise hell like this

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just chain promises by using Promise.all

```
         class Laundry {

          constructor() {
            this.queue = [];
            this.clothes = [];
          }


          addClothes(cloth) {
            this.clothes.push(cloth);

            return this;
          }


          removeClothes(cloth) {
            const clothIndex = this.clothes.findIndex(value => value === cloth);
            this.clothes.splice(clothIndex, 1);

            return this;
          }


          wash() {
            this.clothes = 'washed';

            const item = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 3000)).catch()

            this.queue.push(item);

            return this;
          }


          rinse() {
            this.clothes = 'rinsed';

            const item = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(2), 2000)).catch()

            this.queue.push(item);

            return this;
          }


          finish() {
            return Promise.all(this.queue);
          }
        }


        module.exports = Laundry;
```

then calling like this...

```
const Laundry = require('./laundry');

const laundry = new Laundry();

// class chain methods...
laundry.wash().rinse().finish().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```